# WPF Combo Box selection changed should not update in UI

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using WPF combo box. I need to know how to do the following: when I select the combobox item in the combo box pop up, it should not update in the content. It should only change when I set `SelectedItem` in using Bindings in MVVM.

Please give me any idea.

Comment: did i get it right that you dont want the user to set the combobox value from ui? if yes simply disable the combobox. but then it i have a question, why you use a combobox?...

Comment: Selecting item from popup, will set the content. You can't stop it but in case you don't want selected value from popUp to be set in binded SelectedItem use Binding with `Mode=OneWay`.

Comment: actually,i select the value from combobox, then using SelectedItem property to give the value to some service, and get response from the service. after getting response i need to display to combo box content. but when i select combo box item, it passes value to service,but should not change in UI. i need to update the UI after getting response from UI.

Comment: There is workaround though. I have posted an answer. See if that helps.!!

Comment: i need twoway binding..

Answer (score 0):

Set BindingMode OneWay in Binding. [BindingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BindingMode as OneWay to acheive the same.

```
SelectItem="{Binding YourPropertyName Mode=Oneway}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting item from popup, will set the content. But if you want to stop that as well, you can do that by `manually updating Target on selectionChanged event` and make sure `binding mode is set to OneWay` so that change doesn't make its way to binded selectedItem in source class.

**Sample XAML:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}"
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPropertyInClass, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**In code behind:**

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                       SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var expression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(sender as ComboBox, 
                                                 ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);
    expression.UpdateTarget();
}
```

Here, we are getting Binding expression and manually updating the target on any selection change event.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i did it using UpdateSourcetrigger=LostFocus.

Comment: Simply `LostFocus` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

you may use  `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```
<ComboBox Name="cb_users" DisplayMemberPath="Email"  

SelectedItem="{Binding selectedUser,Mode= TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}"> /ComboBox>
```

Comment: `PropertyChanged` is not going to work here. Have you verified it?

Comment: Yes l have verified,İt is working.Do you use INotifyPropertyChanged?